ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Syncfusion Grid: Chart result not as expected
I have the following table created in SQL:
SQL Table
How can I create a Syncfusion Chart, that is similar to this:
Similar Chart
but instead of Total, Cancelled, etc., change to User
PS:

Important - the table can grow, meaning: now I have 5 users, but in future it will be more

The Total column is not so important


Thanks
I tried the following:
<ejs-chart id="container4" selectionMode="DragXY" enableAnimation="true">
    <e-chart-tooltipsettings enable="true" format="${point.x} : <b>${point.y} </b>">
    </e-chart-tooltipsettings>
    <e-chart-legendsettings visible="true" enableHighlight="true">
    </e-chart-legendsettings>
    <e-chart-zoomsettings enableMouseWheelZooming="true" enableScrollbar="false" enablePinchZooming="true" enableSelectionZooming="true" showToolbar="true"></e-chart-zoomsettings>
    <e-chart-primaryxaxis valueType="Category" labelFormat="{value}"></e-chart-primaryxaxis>
    <e-series-collection>
        <e-series dataSource="@IndexModel.chart4Data" xName="User" width="2" yName="May" name="May" type="@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Line">
             <e-series-marker visible="true" height="7" width="7" shape="@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartShape.Circle" isFilled="true"></e-series-marker>
        </e-series>
    </e-series-collection>
</ejs-chart>

but it's not working as it should.

"but it's not working as it should." -- You have to help us here... we don't know what you mean...

@Dai hi, the result I want to achieve is like in this image, but instead of booking total, Cancelled, etc. should list by users and grouped per months. Every user must have their own series grouped by month. for ex. in this case, I need 5 lines for the 5 users grouped by month, but in the feature the number of users will increase / decrease.

Yes, that's already established - I'm asking you to describe in better detail how it currently behaves.

Don't use Comments to post code - edit your post instead.

@Dai this is how it looks now: image and the code for that is: link
